Concurrency background thread not working
I am currently learning about concurrency and would like to apply this knowledge to a basic calculation app I am developing. My goal is to ensure that two input calculation results are updated in real time, even while the calculations are being performed on a background thread.
However, my code doesn't work and does not update the result in real-time. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving these issues.
Thank you in advance for your help. Below is my code.
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var input1: Double? = nil
    @Published var input2: Double? = nil
    
    @Published var multiplication: Double = 0
    @Published var input1by2: Double = 0
    @Published var input2by1: Double = 0
    
    func multiply() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2 
        else { return }
        
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000)
        let value = input1 * input2
        await MainActor.run {
            self.multiplication = value
        }
    }
    
    func division1() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2
        else { return }
        
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000)
        let value = input1 / input2
        await MainActor.run {
            self.input1by2 = value
        }
    }
    
    func division2() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2
        else { return }
        
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000)
        let value = input2 / input1
        await MainActor.run {
            self.input2by1 = value
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack (spacing: 100) {
                ResultView()
                
                UserInput()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct ResultView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Multiplication: ")
                Text("\(tap.multiplication, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
            .task {
                await tap.multiply()
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input1/Input2: ")
                Text("\(tap.input1by2, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
            .task {
                await tap.division1()
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input2/Input1: ")
                Text("\(tap.input2by1, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
            .task {
                await tap.division2()
            }
        }
        .font(.title3)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
    }
}




struct UserInput: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 1: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input1, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2)
            
            )
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 2: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input2, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2)
            
            )
            
        }
    }
}


You have explained that you have an issue... but not what the issue is.

@Fogmeister the code doesn't work. The result should be updated in real-time, but I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

You need to declare a @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()
in your views hierarchy (eg in ContentView), then pass that model to other views using
.environmentObject(dataModel)

I already declared at the WindowGroup of @main. Also, the code simply works without using concurrency, and I don't think it is environmentObject issue.

The problem is that you're using .task modifier in a wrong way. As its documentation suggests Adds an asynchronous task to perform before this view appears., meaning that the task is called once for each view you attached it to and will never be called again in your example since it is a static view(it doesn't disappear, hence won't reappear). Moreover you failed checking in guard statements for input1 and input2, because they're nil at the moment view appeared(aka when task is called), so you've just left methods.
What you really want to use instead of task here is Combine framework.

Google something like "Combine debounce and usage with text fields in SwiftUI", there're plenty examples in the 'net with very similar problem solution to yours

@Lian yes, I would assume that “the code doesn’t work”. But that also doesn’t explain what the problem is. When writing a question you should explain what IS happening. Not what ISN'T happening. The code not working could mean it crashes, it doesn’t run at all, the buttons look wrong. It’s always best to describe what is happening and what you expected to happen instead.

"The code doesn't work" is a maddeningly unhelpful thing to say. It provides no useful information. Tell us, in detail, what you are seeing, how that fails to meet your desired results, and what you have done to try to problem-solve.

Try this approach removing the .task{...} from the ResultView
and placing the equivalent in the
UserInput when the user submit the input (in this example when the user
submit the second input, the approach is flexible).
Also note the use of @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel().
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var input1: Double? = nil
    @Published var input2: Double? = nil
    
    @Published var multiplication: Double = 0
    @Published var input1by2: Double = 0
    @Published var input2by1: Double = 0
    
    func multiply() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2
        else { return }
        
        let value = input1 * input2
        await MainActor.run {
            self.multiplication = value
        }
    }
    
    func division1() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2
        else { return }
        
        let value = input1 / input2
        await MainActor.run {
            self.input1by2 = value
        }
    }
    
    func division2() async {
        guard
            let input1 = input1,
            let input2 = input2
        else { return }

        let value = input2 / input1
        await MainActor.run {
            self.input2by1 = value
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataModel = DataModel() // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack (spacing: 100) {
                ResultView()
                UserInput()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .environmentObject(dataModel) // <--- here
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Multiplication: ")
                Text("\(tap.multiplication, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input1/Input2: ")
                Text("\(tap.input1by2, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input2/Input1: ")
                Text("\(tap.input2by1, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
        }
        .font(.title3)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
    }
}

struct UserInput: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 1: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input1, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2))
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 2: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input2, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .onSubmit {  // <--- here
                Task {
                    await tap.multiply()
                    await tap.division1()
                    await tap.division2()
                }
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2))
            
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
with .onSubmit for input1
struct UserInput: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 1: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input1, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .onSubmit {  // <--- here
                calculate()
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2))
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Input 2: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                
                TextField("123", value: $tap.input2, format: .number)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            .onSubmit {  // <--- here
                calculate()
            }
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.blue.gradient, lineWidth: 2))
            
        }
    }
    
    func calculate() { // <--- here
        Task {
            await tap.multiply()
            await tap.division1()
            await tap.division2()
        }
    }
}


Thanks, everyone for the headache. Unfortunately, the code still hasn't worked, and no update in real-time.

the code I show in my answer works very well. If you have other code that interferes with the processing, then show the code that we can compile and run to reproduce your problem. Updated my answer using .onSubmit for input1 as well. Try my code as is and let me know if this does not work for you.

I copied and pasted all my code. The only difference will be having the structs in a different folder. What is wrong with mine !!!

Thank you y'all. The code works. I just need to use .onChange instead of .onSubmit such as .onChange(of: tap.input2) { calculate() }.

if my code helped, consider accepting the answer by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

I did it and it didn't work. That's where I have the idea to use .onChange
